# Real projects on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have just started to work with google app engine, and I would like to see real projects, which use this service. These projects should be written in Java (desirable)

If anyone has a link (GitHub or other link with information) I will be very grateful

UPD: 
[i find only link with companies who are using Google Cloud Platform to build robust and scalable apps](https://cloud.google.com/customers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the guestbook sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-java

I don't think you will find the actual source code of any real/live site.

Comment: I've already done this example [link](http://valid-aquifer-671.appspot.com/)   
I do not need the source code  
I want to understand the scale of applications can be do with this service 
I would like to see links to a good working sites 
Thank you

Comment: then take a look here: https://cloud.google.com/customers/ i don't think there is a bigger site not in this list

Comment: all discussions finished in 2010, and hard for me to to understand the relevance of the service

Comment: as you can see from the customers page, app engine is still going STRONG. it does not get a lot of hype, but it's a very solid and mature platform.

Comment: i looked his site https://www.khanacademy.org/

please tell me about the features compared with a simple design, as app Engine works with Spring MVC and what problems you encountered when developing your applications?
I will be very grateful

Comment: it does work with Spring MVC. it's really not a discussion for the comments here. there are ample resources on the web. Please try to ask more concrete questions

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of [thundr](http://3wks.github.io/thundr/), a lightweight java webmvc specifically designed for cloud and PaaS deployments.

I've built a lot of apps on top of thundr, the majority being appengine apps. I know of at least 40 or so apps built and deployed on appengine using the framework, of varying scale.

One of them is listed on the [cloud.google.com/customers/](https://cloud.google.com/customers/) list.

There are many real projects running in this environment, however I agree you're not going to have much luck finding source for people's services.